# How do i use Canadian tickers in yfinance?

Tags: python, yfinance

Cant seem to find any documentation, i assumed adding .To or the like would do it but im at a loss. Anyone familiar with yfinance?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an error pulling "Fundamentals" when getting certain stock info. Another post advised me to add an exception in yfinance's base.py file. All works well after that.